# npm run dev isnt starting a server on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-start

I am working on a website using react.js and tailwindcss.
I wanted to see how far Ive gotten just to find out that the "npm run dev" command is not starting a server on localhost.
Does anyone know how I can reslove this issue as Ive never seen this before

I have tried running the commannd on a new project to see if it was reserved to this project or a global one. This also did not work

Comment: do you have `npm run dev` setup in the scripts property of your `package.json`? might help to show the `package.json` too

Answer (score 0):

Just add `node app.js` in your `scripts.dev` of `package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node app.js",
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. While trying this out I found out I made a mistake in setting up the tailwind-config.json